# Create folders in Chinese using mkdir() in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a PHP which i am using to create a folders and subfolders using PHP. I want to fetch data from my database that is is Chinese and create folders in Chinese. Below is my code:

```
<?php 
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "dtable";

  //session_start();
  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error());
  }

  $upload = 'E://demo';

  $str = '';
  $str1 = '';
  if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
    $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
    $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE username = '$userid' and password = '$pid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$target = $upload.'/'.$row['week'].'/'.$row['day1'].'/'.$row['client'].'/'.$row['brand'].'/'.$row['sn'].'/';
if(!file_exists($target))
     {
       mkdir($target,0777,true);
     }
?>
```

The data in my database is in Chinese. This works completely fine when the data is in English but as soon as I change it to Chinese it starts giving me error.

Comment: mkdir() function. Invalid argument.

Comment: what does var_dump($target); returns ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` to change character string encoding.

[image]

```
$dir_name = "測試/測試2";
$dir_name = iconv("UTF-8", "big5", $dir_name);
// $dir_name = mb_convert_encoding($dir_name, "big5", "UTF-8");
$path = "clients/$dir_name";    
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```